# Add Sound Sample player to the GUI: visual bug

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, game-development, godot

i am still learning Godot and trying to add a sound to my game using the SamplePlayer. Upon selecting it from the left tree, it is supposed to open a basic sound editor that allows you to select the audio file, however in my case there is a visual bug that prevent me from doing so.
Tried to resize it but it won't budge...

My Laptop : ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, intel core i7
Godot : 2.0.3 stable

Any ideas if there is a workaround for this issue ? 
(Bottom right)

[image: Screenshot showing the visual bug]

Godot : https://godotengine.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved, turned out that this pop-up isn't mandatory, the sound file can be selected from the right menu after creating new AudioStreamOggVorbis -> load -> select the .ogg file.